Machine Learning vs Deep Learning? in context of Generative AI vs Discrimative AI?
I know that deep learning is subset of Machine learning
But is it correct that classical machine Learning algorithms mainly focus on implementing Discriminative AI while Deep learning algorithms implement both Generative AI and Discriminative AI?

So transformers (deep learning architecture) are the ones behind GenAI. Machine Learning has no contribution to GenAI. So yes it’s correct I think.
